# Forticlient SSL VPN disconnects after 5-15 minutes

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I'm having some problems to maintain my VPN connection using FortiClient 6.0.2. This VPN is from a company and some users does not have this problem.

The log only shows this when the VPN is disconnected:

> 19/10/2018 08:41:53   Information VPN FortiSslvpn: 16312: Ras:
>   connection to fortissl terminated 19/10/2018
>   08:41:53  Notice  VPN date=2018-10-19 time=08:41:52 logver=1
>   type=traffic level=notice sessionid=990872160 hostname=NB-003837
>   pcdomain=company.local uid=48C9761B34264A7B96C2FEAE8CB346F4
>   devid=FCT8001460591996 fgtserial=N/A emsserial=N/A regip=N/A
>   srcname=sslvpn srcproduct=N/A srcip=10.0.62.2 srcport=N/A
>   direction=outbound dstip=vpn.company.com remotename=N/A
>   dstport=10443 user=dherik.so proto=6 rcvdbyte=12965012537
>   sentbyte=4296749006 utmaction=passthrough utmevent=vpn
>   threat=disconnect vd=N/A fctver=6.0.2.0128 os="Microsoft Windows 10
>   Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 17134)" usingpolicy="" service=
>   url=N/A userinitiated=0 browsetime=N/A

I don't know if is something on my side or in the company side. On the FortiClient forum they have a similar problem and the problem was solved changing the [users to IPSec](https://forum.fortinet.com/tm.aspx?m=165638):

> I had this exact same issue with SSLVPN for my company. Constant
>   disconnections every 2-10 minutes at random for all users. The only
>   fix I could come up with was to switch everyone over to IPSec. Holds
>   solid and never drops.

But before contact the company about my problem, I would like to understand and have more information about what's happening.